# how to send a push Notification when message received from my app

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I'm writing a simple message app using firebase when a user receives a message I want it to play a sound. and show a notification if the app is closed. the code I used works in emulator whilst the app is open but as soon as the app is closed or minimised it does nothing. also, when I try to use a real device instead of the emulator it does nothing.

I thought it could be something to do with permissions but I read that notifications are like the internet permission and are not needed.

```
private void Display_Messages() {
    ListView listOfMessages = findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, 
ChatMessage.class,
            R.layout.message, 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int 
   position) {
            // Get references to the views of message.xml
                TextView messageText = v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
                TextView messageUser = v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                TextView messageTime = v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            // Set their text
            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());

            // Format the date before showing it
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy 
(HH:mm:ss)",
                    model.getMessageTime()));

            //Define Notification Manager
            NotificationManager notificationManager = 
(NotificationManager) 
getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

//Define sound URI
            Uri soundUri = 
RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("New Message from: " + 
USERNAME_STRING)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSound(soundUri); //This sets the sound to play

//Display notification
            notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
        }
    };
    listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
```

it works while app open but only on emulator test device

Comment: would i need a Gcm Receiver perhaps?

Comment: Did you register you FirebaseMessagingService in your manifest?

Comment: no, as I use a local notification builder i use firebase only for the actual message content. it works on the emulator this is the strange bit,

Comment: Check application settings, to see if notifications are actually enabled. In some cases system can turn of notifications for the app

Comment: i do believe it could be something to do with Version my phone is. tried it on another phone and its working while the app is open